How to show name instead of ID in same table multiple times with empty values?
I have 2 tables. Table 1:
ID, ReceiveID, ProcessID, DeliverID
1      1          1          
2      1          2          3
3      3                

Table 2:
ID, Name
1     Jack
2     Mary
3     Paul

I want to get:
Table1ID, Receiver, Processor, Delivered
1           Jack      Jack       
2           Jack      Mary       Paul
3           Paul            

Can anyone please help me to build the query?
I tried:
SELECT a.Table1ID, b.name, bb.name, bc.name
FROM Table1 as a
JOIN Table2 as b ON a.ReceiveID = b.ID
JOIN Table2 as bb ON a.ProcessID = b.ID
JOIN Table2 as bc ON a.DeliverID = b.ID

but did not work.

You must use left join to allow the rows to be preserved also when some id are null:
select tab1.id, rec.name, proc.name, delv.name
from tab1
left join tab2 rec on tab1.receive_id = rec.id
left join tab2 proc on tab1.process_id = proc.id
left join tab2 delv on tab1.deliver_id = delv.id


Thank you very much. This works.
I thought JOIN and LEFT JOIN work the same.
